# using permission handler at main flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get user permission at the start of the app inside main but i get and exception.

```
void main() async {
    final permission = Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    if (await permission.isGranted){
    }
```

Error:

> Exception has occurred.
> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code below, I think it can solve your problem, I tested it and worked for me. Instead of getting the permission in **main()**, it uses the stateful widget MyApp, tries to get the permission in **initState()**, uses async function **_getPermission()** to await the user's response and with **setState()** updates the permission grant state in **_permission** member.

In the **build** method you can decide what your app should do if permission is granted or not. In this example I only output a single message depending on the permission. For example you can return your MaterialApp when granted, and a warning message if not, anything you like.

You might be aware of this, but one more thing: if the user permanently denies  permission, this solution will not prompt again, so you have to handle this case, if your app cannot work without this, you can offer the user to go into settings and enable it there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _permission = false;

  void _getPermission() async {
    final grant = await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
    setState(() {
      _permission = grant;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String message =
        _permission ? 'Permission granted' : 'Permission not granted';

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text(message))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which package do you use for permission handling, but if you use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), you have to add **request()** before **isGranted**:

```
if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {
}
```

Or if you want just to get permission status without asking for it:

```
var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
if (status.isDenied) {
}
```

Comment: I am using permission handler package, the code works in other part of the app but not in main function

Comment: I am not sure you can ask for permissions before actually running your application. This package uses UI elements to ask for permission, and at this point in main (before runApp(MyApp()) for example) these might not be accessible yet.

Comment: You can try  to add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); in the first line of main(), but I don't really think it will help.

Comment: I would try to ask for permission somewhere later in the code, for example use a stateful application widget and add the permission handling in the build method.

Comment: I want the system to wait for folder permission before continuing to execute the remaining code, i use async await, but its not working